# laravel get Data from table using model in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to get vendor_name and user who assign order to vendor in view. But every time i got this error

> ErrorException in b6bb559eccdc8a2d45a2d2d6ce89e8e217411386.php line 26:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\ftdindia\resources\views\view\Orders\allorder.blade.php)
>   in b6bb559eccdc8a2d45a2d2d6ce89e8e217411386.php line 26
>   at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44

my codes are given below

Controller for Order

```
public function allorder(){
    $orders = OrderGrid::paginate(100);

    return view ('view.Orders.allorder', ['orders' => $orders]);


    //dd($orders->all());

}
```

Here is My Model

```
class OrderGrid extends model{

    protected $table = 'order_grids';

    public function vendor() { 
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    } 

    public function assignedBy() { 
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'vendor_assigned_by_user');
    } 
}
```

Here is my view

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
<tr>
    <td> {{ $i }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->order_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->vendor->username }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->assignedBy->username }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->delivery_city }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->delivery_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->delivery_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->order_statuss }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->order_status }}</td>
    <td>
        @if(!$order->vendor_id)
            Unassigned
        @else
            Assigned
        @endif
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<?php $i +=1; ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: which one is line -26 in your view??

Comment: 26 line in view <td>{{ $order->vendor->username }}</td>

Comment: try changing method name "vendor()" to something else "order_vendor()" in your model. and then use it in view like - $order->order_vendor->username. based on this link - http://laravel.io/forum/01-22-2015-eloquent-belongsto-not-returning-relationships

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
<tr>
    <td> {{ $i }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->order_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->vendor->username }}</td>  inspite of this do <td>{{ !is_null($order->vendorName) ? $order->vendorName->username : null }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->assignedBy->username }}</td> and same here also <td>{{ !is_null($order->assignedBy) ? $order->assignedBy->username : null }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->delivery_city }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->delivery_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->delivery_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->order_statuss }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->order_status }}</td>
    <td>
        @if(!$order->vendor_id)
            Unassigned
        @else
            Assigned
        @endif
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<?php $i +=1; ?>
@endforeach
```

and in Model

```
public function vendorName() { 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User', 'vendor_id', 'id');
    } 

    public function assignedBy() { 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User', 'assigned_by', 'id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting relates to how you are calling the `vendor()` function in the `$order` collection.

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) are a good place for a solid understanding on this, but essentially all Eloquent relationships are defined via functions and so you may call those functions to obtain an instance of the relationship without actually executing the relationship queries.

As such it needs to be:

```
<td>{{ $order->vendor()->username }}</td>
```

Nothing that we are now chaining vendor() rather than vendor.

Comment: not working..... i had made some changes but this return only 1..... here are the changes...
{{ !is_null($order->assignedBy ? $order->assignedBy->username: null) }}

Comment: again you are doing the same mistake try `assignedBy()` instead of `assignedBy`.

Comment: hmmm thanks for that.... i've got the solution actually you are that letting me know there is issue in view